# Insert QML code in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, qml, pug

I'm writting a simple video streaming app with Node.js and I'm using the WebChimera plugin.  With chimera, the player config is written in QML and I must include it in my .jade page and of course, there's many errors when jade compiles.

Is there a way to include QML in jade?

Comment: I don't know what is jade but why just don't use separate .qml files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm going to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Jade try including an iframe(src='/qmlfiles/my.qml') and create a subfolder called qmlfiles in your /public folder.  And then put your qml content in that my.qml file.  Express will then see that since qmlfiles is in /public it won't try to interpret it.  This is based upon the assumption that .qml has some mime association to it that a browser would understand.

If not, then my.qml might instead just be my.html and it could include QML content.  Again, locating it under /public would mean that Express doesn't use the rendering of Jade in order to try to deal with it.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks! The only thing left is when I read the video, the my.qml file is downloaded by my browser...

Comment: All goes well after renaming qml in html.

Comment: Nicely done.  I have to do this same sort of technique for embedded Google maps within my apps.  It's just easier to iframe the content versus try to get jade to leave it alone.

Comment: And don't forget that you can also do inline style or refer to your externally-stored class information for that iframe if you want, say, to adjust the width/height.  iframe.myIframeClass(src='') or iframe(src='', height='100', width='100')

Comment: Nice Michael, thanx for the tips.